# volatile table usage in Informatica

Tags: teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In my Informatica mapping, I need to do the following activities:

1. creating 'A' volatile table
2. inserting records into 'A' table, from 'B' normal table
3. again I want to insert records into 'C' normal table using 'A' volatile table.

If my question is not clear, just post your comments and I will try to clarify it.

Comment: What have you tried?  And with what are you having trouble?  In other words, are you asking how to create a volatile table in Teradata or how to get Informatica to run the code?  Also, give a simple example of your three tables (A, B, and C).

Comment: Hi, I dont want to create in Terdata. I want volatile table creation in Informatica mapping for example in SQL TRANSFORMATION .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any logic to impliment after creating the volatile table? what kind of logic(Simple/Complex)? Based on my understanding, here is what you can do. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

You can do this in 2 ways.

1. create a Stored proc which creates volatile table based on other Multiset table, Impliment logic (If any ) then push it over to Other Multiset table (C)
2. - Read from B, Use SQL transformation to create Volatile table, and then insert to Volatile table
   - use volatile table as source and use rest of the transformations and then to Table C.